# php and sql server stored procedure executing

Tags: php, stored-procedures, sqlsrv

I have a stored procedure that do a login proccess and in different conditions return different value in same structure.

this is my code:

```
create PROCEDURE [dbo].[I_SPCheckUserLogin]
 @username nvarchar(50),
 @password varchar(max)

AS
Begin
    declare @incorrect_pass_msg nvarchar(MAX) = N'کاربر گرامی کلمه عبور نادرست است';
    declare @login_success_pass_msg nvarchar(MAX) = N'کاربر گرامی عملیات ورود با موفقیت انجام شد';
    declare @user_not_exists_msg nvarchar(MAX) = N'چنین کاربری یافت نشد';
    declare @lock_user_msg nvarchar(MAX) = N'کاربر گرامی به دلایل امنیتی شما قادر به ورود نمی باشید';
    declare @change_pass_msg nvarchar(MAX) = N'به دلایل امنیتی باید کلمه عبور تغییر یابد';

    declare @error_number int = 0;
    declare @msg nvarchar(100);
    declare @version nvarchar(50);
    declare @rule_lock_login_time int;
    declare @rule_attempt_login int;
    declare @rule_expire_days int;
    select @version = ValueI from I_Rules where RuleName = 'Version';
    select @rule_lock_login_time = ValueI from I_Rules where RuleName = 'LockLoginTime';
    select @rule_attempt_login = ValueI from I_Rules where RuleName = 'AttemptToLogin';
    select @rule_expire_days = ValueI from I_Rules where RuleName = 'PasswordExpireDays';
    declare @md5_number int;

    select top 1 @md5_number = Value from SplitString(@version,'.') order by Id desc;
    declare @m_password nvarchar(MAX);
    set @m_password = (select dbo.Md5Generator(@password , @md5_number));

        declare @uid int ,
            @uname nvarchar(max),
            @upass nvarchar(max),
            @ulast_login_date nvarchar(10),
            @ulast_login_time nvarchar(10),
            @ulock_login_time nvarchar(10),
            @umust_change_pass bit,
            @upass_never_expire bit,
            @uattempt_login int,
            @ulast_change_pass_date nvarchar(10);

        select @uid = Id,
            @uname = Username,
            @upass = [Password],
            @ulast_login_date = LastLoginDate,
            @ulast_login_time = LastLoginTime,
            @ulock_login_time = LockLoginTime,
            @umust_change_pass = UserMustChangePassword,
            @upass_never_expire = PasswordNeverExpire,
            @uattempt_login = AttemptToLogin,
            @ulast_change_pass_date = LastChangePasswordDate
        from I_Users 
        where Username = @username and 
            IsActive='true';


        declare @server_time nvarchar(10),
            @server_date nvarchar(10);

        select @server_date = [Date],
            @server_time = [Time] 
        from dbo.GetShamsiDateTime();

        if(@uname is null)
            begin
                set @error_number = 1;
                set @msg = @user_not_exists_msg;
                select @error_number error , @msg [message];
                return;
            end
        else
            begin
            if(@ulock_login_time is not null)
            begin
                if( @server_time <= (select dbo.AddMinuteToTime(@ulock_login_time, @rule_lock_login_time)))
                begin
                    set @error_number = 1;
                    set @msg = @lock_user_msg;
                    select @error_number error , @msg [message];
                    update I_Users Set LockLoginTime=@server_time Where Id=@uid;
                    return;
                end
                else
                begin
                    update I_Users 
                        set LastLoginDate = @server_date,
                            LastLoginTime = @server_time,
                            LockLoginTime = null,
                            AttemptToLogin = 0
                        where Id = @uid;
                    if(@@ERROR !=0)
                    begin
                        select 3 error , 'update faild' [message];
                        return;
                    end
                end
            end
            if(@upass != @m_password)
            begin
                declare @tmp table(uattemp_login nvarchar(max));
                update I_Users 
                set AttemptToLogin = AttemptToLogin + 1 
                output inserted.AttemptToLogin into @tmp
                where Id = @uid;
                if(@@ERROR !=0)
                begin
                    select 3 error , 'update faild' [message];
                    return;
                end

                set @uattempt_login = (select uattemp_login from @tmp);

                if @uattempt_login = @rule_attempt_login
                begin
                    update I_Users set LockLoginTime = @server_time where Id=@uid
                    if(@@ERROR !=0)
                    begin
                        select 3 error , 'update faild' [message];
                        return;
                    end
                end
                set @error_number = 1;
                set @msg = @incorrect_pass_msg;
                select @error_number error , @msg [message];
                return;
            end
            else
            begin
                if @umust_change_pass = 'true'
                begin
                    set @error_number = 2;
                    set @msg = @change_pass_msg;
                    select @error_number error , @msg [message];
                    return;
                end
                else
                begin
                    if @upass_never_expire = 'false'
                    begin
                        if @server_date> (select [date] from AddDaysToDate_Custom((select dbo.ShamsitoMiladi(@ulast_change_pass_date)),@rule_expire_days))
                        begin
                            set @error_number = 2;
                            set @msg = @change_pass_msg;
                            select @error_number error , @msg [message];
                            return;
                        end
                    end
                    update I_Users 
                    set LastLoginDate = @server_date,
                        LastLoginTime = @server_time,
                        LockLoginTime = null,
                        AttemptToLogin = 0
                    where Id = @uid;
                    if(@@ERROR !=0)
                    begin
                        select 3 error , 'update faild' [message];
                        return;
                    end
                    set @error_number = 0;
                    set @msg = @login_success_pass_msg;
                    select @error_number error , @msg [message];

                    return;
                end
            end
        end
end
```

the problem is that when execute this stored procedure like this :

```
$username = trim($username);
$password = trim($password);
$dbconn = new  db_connection();


$select_statement = "execute I_SPCheckUserLogin '{$username}','{$password}'";
echo $select_statement;
$result = $dbconn->do_sql_command($select_statement);

$count = 0;

$row = $dbconn->fetch_array($result);


if ($row['error'] == '0') {
echo '<br/>';

    $this->load->library('session');
    $ci =& get_instance();
    $data = array();
    $data['username'] = $username;
    $data['password'] = $password;
    $data['system_id'] = $system_id;
    $ci->session->set_userdata('user_info', $data);
    redirect('control_panel/index');
} else
    echo $row['message'];
```

the problem after a lot of test is that when executing the update statements in this stored procedure the rest of the stored procedure not executing from php 
but in the sql server management studio execute like charm

sorry about my english

Comment: What is the reason you do the whole login process in a stored procedure???

Comment: it's not just a login process i will do alot more in it but i want to do most of the work on the stored procedure because this stored procedure will be used more than once and i saw it better in this way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok sorry for the delay but i found the solution

i must put the command that is : SET NOCOUNT ON

SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
interfering with SELECT statements.

it solved my problem